# Simple helper to display field if exists

Tags: ruby-on-rails

So i am bothering with simple problem i guess, to be specific:
I have a simple view, where is check if the user has an email, if so - it displays it. I want to make it more gentle, so want create a method to check if the field exist, here is the view:

```
    <ul class="list-unstyled">
        <li>Contact email: <%= @lumber.user.email if @lumber.user.email %></li>
        <li>Contact phone:<%= @lumber.user.phone if @lumber.user.phone %></li>
        <li>Website: <%= link_to "#{@lumber.user.website}", "http://#{@lumber.user.website}" if @lumber.user.website%></li>
        <li>where to find: <%= @lumber.location %></li>
    </ul>
```

I tried to write a method in application_helper :

```
  def self.display(info)
    self.user.info if self.user.info
  end
```

And call it : `@lumber.display(email)` but getting error:

```
undefined local variable or method `email' for #<#<Class:0x007fbcd1e141b0>:0x007fbcd1e0f6d8>
```

Any hints? kinda new to RoR

Comment: i want to know about this line `<%= @lumber.user.email if @lumber.user.email %>` if email exists it will display email, if it wont exists it will display nothing even if check is not there, why you need to a check. besides i think you should do this `<%= @lumber.user.try(:email) %>` without check, so that it wont crash even if user is not there. just an opinion

Comment: Yeah mate I know about that it will be blank field, its just for me to learn. thanks for advice with that .try !

Answer (score 0):

#### Problem with the current approach:

```
  def self.display(info)
    self.user.info if self.user.info
  end
```

If you define a method with `self.` in a class, then it will be a class method of the class and then you have to call the method like this: `ClassName.method_name`. But, in this case, you don't want that. You just want a simple helper method `display` which will take an object and return the `object.user.email` if exists. You would also want to make sure and `object.user` and `object.user.email` both exist.

#### Solution:

```
  def display(lumber)
    if lumber.user && lumber.user.email
      lumber.user.email
    else
      'Email Not Present!'
    end
  end
```

Then, call it like: `display(@lumber)` from the view.

Comment: Thanks for reply, this kind of solution i managed to write myself , but still i would have to create few methods to display each field.

Comment: You can  define other methods in the same class and then use them inside `display` method.

Answer (score 0):

What you are trying to do is called metaprogramming. In your `helper`, `info` is a variable name, and it's NOT related to `self.user.info`.

`@lumber.display(email)` is trying to find a variable named email which is the error.

So, let's do this:

```
@lumber.display("email")
```

and in the helper

```
def self.display(var_name)
  self.user.instance_variable_get(var_name) if self.user.instance_variable_defined?(var_name)
end
```

Hope this helps

Comment: `undefined method write for "email":String` I like your solution, but there is something not working correct, as far as i remember I read that this kind of error occurs with .self.

Comment: If this is your solution, the `display` method shouldn't be in the helper, but in the model. Also it shouldn't be `def self.display(...)`, but `def display(...)`.

Comment: I did not think it will be so hard to implement such small thing, sadly ur way is not working neither :( getting error of  `email' is not allowed as an instance variable name` any hints where can i read some informations about that kind of things ?